# $f$ holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ extends to Analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-continuation

I have the following question:

> Prove of give a counterexample: Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on its closure. Then, $f$ extends to a analytic map on $B_{(0,R)}$ for some $R > 1$.

I am really not sure whether the statement is true. I can't think of any functions that are analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ but not on the boundary, so it seems like the claim might be true. But, I do not know how to define the function outside of $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: $R$ should be greater than $1$, right?

Comment: Yes, let me edit

Answer (score 3):

You might try $f(z)=\sqrt{1-z}$.

Comment: I like this example, thanks for your response